# how to allocate several numbers to several groups as evenly as possible on matlab 2014a?

Tags: matlab

Now, there are m numbers and I want allocate them into n groups as evenly as possible. m is bigger than n.

For example,If m=17, n=3, I want to get groups with 6,5,6 elements in each of them.

If m=16, n=3, then, these three groups have 5,6,5 elements in each of them.

Comment: Would `6,6,5` and `6,5,5` be OK distributions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `floor` and `rem` (similar to `mod`):

```
m = randi([10 100]);
n = randi([2,9]);
x = floor(m/n);
r = rem(m,n);
v = [x*ones(1,n-r),(x+1)*ones(1,r)]
(sum(v) == m) && (max(diff(v)) <= 1) % sanity check
```